# Connection to postgres from typescript hangs

Tags: typescript, postgresql, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to connect to a Postgres database from typescript. I'm using `sequelize-typescript` as an ORM. My problem is that the script gets stuck on `await sequelize.sync();`. Here's the `sequelize.ts` file:

```
import {Sequelize} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { config } from './config/config';


const c = config.dev;

// Instantiate new Sequelize instance!
export const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  "username": c.username,
  "password": c.password,
  "database": c.database,
  "host":     c.host,

  dialect: 'postgres',
  storage: ':memory:',
});
```

And here's the model class file `Product.ts`:

```
  import {Table, Column, Model, HasMany, PrimaryKey, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, ForeignKey} from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table
export class Product extends Model<Product> {

    @Column
    public brand: string;

    @Column
    public price: number;

    @Column
    public description!: string;

    @Column
    public imgUrl!: string;

    @Column
    public cateogry: string;

  
}
```

Here's the `server.ts` where I use sequelize:

```
    (async () => {
 

  
  await sequelize.addModels(V0MODELS);

  //It get's stuck here
  await sequelize.sync();

  const app = express();
  const port =  8100; // default port to listen
  
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8100");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
  });

  app.use('/api/v0/', IndexRouter);

  // Root URI call
  app.get( "/", async ( req, res ) => {
    res.send( "/api/v0/" );
  } );
  

  // Start the Server
  app.listen( port, () => {
      console.log( `server running http://localhost:${ port }` );
      console.log( `press CTRL+C to stop server, please :)` );
  } );
})();
```

And here is `package.json` content:

```
{
  "name": "bagsshoes-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node .",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only ./src/server.ts",
    "prod": "tsc && node ./www/server.js",
    "clean": "rd /s /q www/>nul 2>&1|echo.>nul",
    "build": "npm run clean && tsc && cp -rf src/config www/config && cp .npmrc www/.npmrc && cp package.json www/package.json && cd www && zip -r Archive.zip . && cd ..",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Fahima Mokhtari",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.2",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "pg": "^7.9.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "sequelize": "^5.3.5",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^0.6.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.27",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.17",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.27.44",
    "@types/validator": "^10.11.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.40",
    "tslint": "^5.18.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```

I tried `try` and `catch` but it showed no error, which got me confused even more.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**PS:**

I'm using windows and Node V14.7.0

Comment: Try adding force option to true. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066755/how-does-sequelize-sync-work-specifically-the-force-option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066755/how-does-sequelize-sync-work-specifically-the-force-option) for more information. Maybe sequelize is blocked beacuse the table(s) already exist(s).

Comment: Alreay tried it, it ddi not work for me unfortunately. The Databse contains no table

Comment: Enable loggin and check what sequelize is doing under the hood. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427501/how-can-i-see-the-sql-generated-by-sequelize-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427501/how-can-i-see-the-sql-generated-by-sequelize-js).

Comment: @CarloCorradini Sequelize log by default the queries! No ! ? the doc is saying so https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#logging !

Comment: @MohamedAllal We are trying to figure what is the problem. Maybe the logging in the project has been disabled (we don't know). Having the logs is commonly very useful.

Comment: Sure ! it's just that i read it before and said sequelize log by default! So that doesn't help! but yes it may be disabled! I suggested DEBUG=* (some libs use debug module) But i guess sequelize doesn't! The best way is to log in the src code through node modules ! https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/4097aaa0e8b9c988192e0c1ecc649b9b2fdc9502/src/sequelize.js#L763 The place of hangouts are model.sync or hooks! Authenticate should not run as there is modules! Otherwise i suggested testing authentication (doc) https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#testing-the-connection

Comment: For the logging i more of wanted to get extra infromation! About the logging! And that's why i asked in the first place! And yea! a good reasoning is to assume the worst! there is too the wrapper of sequelize-typescript! Which can change things! Even though i doubt that! Thank you too!

Comment: @CarloCorradini after testing with authenticate and logging! The hanging is happening there! Meaning it's a connection problem! The credentials are right too!

Comment: Yup, it is a connection problem. Although the credentials are correct, connection cannot be established

Comment: I've updated my question and added package.json .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### NOTICE

TLDS! (TOO LONG DO SKIM)! The answer is long and rich! You can skim ! It's well formated!

**If you are in big hurry**!
You can check **Authenticate** section, **Sequelize-typescript (not sequelize)** section, **Sequelize-typescript** section.

And **better you can go directly** to **HELL** section! Get to know nodejs **v14 HELL**! (Go directly to the end! Well a bit above).

Check too **FIX (Postgres v14 HELL)**

I started and before knowing i found myself wrote too much!

## SUPER GUIDE

Basically sequelize should not just hang! But throw an error!

### Looking at code source

By looking at `sync` code [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/4097aaa0e8b9c988192e0c1ecc649b9b2fdc9502/src/sequelize.js#L763)

```
 async sync(options) {
    // ...

    // no models defined, just authenticate
    if (!models.length) {
      await this.authenticate(options);
    } else {
      for (const model of models) await model.sync(options);
    }
    if (options.hooks) {
      await this.runHooks('afterBulkSync', options);
    }
    return this;
  }
```

One easily can see the hanging possiblities!

### Logging

To debug such anomalies first of all it's important to have good **logging**!

And you can check how to add logging here! Even though normally sequelize have the logging of the query activated by default!

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#logging

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:', {
  // Choose one of the logging options
  logging: console.log,                  // Default, displays the first parameter of the log function call
  logging: (...msg) => console.log(msg), // Displays all log function call parameters
  logging: false,                        // Disables logging
  logging: msg => logger.debug(msg),     // Use custom logger (e.g. Winston or Bunyan), displays the first parameter
  logging: logger.debug.bind(logger)     // Alternative way to use custom logger, displays all messages
});
```

### Check the authentication

If not logging happen! That may means that sequelize didn't anything and is just hanging at the start! To test authentication and if the connection is working!

You can test with **authenticate**:

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#testing-the-connection

```
try {
  console.log('Gonna authenticate'); // <== to make sure console.log is working and not overrided!
  await sequelize.authenticate();
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
}
```

If you get no logging! And `Gonna authenticate` printed just ok! Then the process is hanging on **authenticate**. Which suggest a problem in authentication!

#### Check your credentials

Make sure you didn't make any mistakes!

#### Check connectivity from psql or some other external client

- If it doesn't work! It suggest a problem with postgres server! Or some config!
- If it does work! Then the problem is in nodejs! And your program!

#### DON'T FORGET TO INSTALL THE POSTGRES DRIVER (Or your db driver)

As per the doc: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#installing

```sh
# One of the following:
$ npm install --save pg pg-hstore # Postgres
$ npm install --save mysql2
$ npm install --save mariadb
$ npm install --save sqlite3
$ npm install --save tedious # Microsoft SQL Server
```

One of the commands! Make sure you didn't forget that!

## Understanding what's happening and debugging better! (code source logging)

The best way to debug! And really determine where the problem is happening! Is by adding logs to the **source code** itself! A **fast way** for me is to **directly do that on `node_modules`**. I opened git on sequelize repo! Made a search! Determined the place of `sync`, `authenticate`, `query`! All reside in **`sequelize.js`**! you can check [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/4097aaa0e8b9c988192e0c1ecc649b9b2fdc9502/src/sequelize.js#L763)! One can CTRL + F to get to the methods `> authenticate(` [add the `(`]. Any way! You can do the same in `node_modules`! And start adding logs! You'll know in which part the problem is happening! Which help you debug the problem!

The other way is to **fork**! And use your fork! And just work better!

But mmm! **node_modules is a fast way**! You can **take a copy**! too! To make sure you don't loose your logs! Once you update! At the end **clean** by just removing the whole module! And reinstall! Or just reverse the logs creation (undo)! I find it an interesting way for debugging!

### But it should throw an error

Normally it should! By seeing the code source you can know better! Normally an error should be thrown! But if a process get hanged! And no error is thrown! Then you can expect a result like this! Here that can be the driver missing! Also make sure `console.log`. Is working all right! And the last thing! MMM may be it's a problem with `nodejs` itself (see the last section).

### I'm using sequelize-typescript (not sequelize)

Very important to know! Sequelize-typescript is just a sequelize wrapper! That was there to add typescript support! It provide decorators and some features! Also From sequelize v5 ! Typescript is supported directly in sequelize! See here
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html
sequelize-typescript in the latest version! Turned to use too the native declaration types of sequelize!

As sequelize-typecript wrap sequelize! Make sure to verify sequelize documentation!

To note too there is some people **shouting**: Don't use decorators! mmmm! mmm! And another mmmm!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60369189/7668448

### Sequelize-typescript

If you are using sequelize-typescript make sure the version of `sequelize-typescript` and `sequelize` do **match**! As per there doc `V5` of sequelize! I guess `V6` too should do! And `v1` for sequelize-typescript!

```sh
npm install sequelize@5 sequelize-typescript@1
```

And don't forget the typescript needed packages as per there doc!
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript

(You can check and verify all those information in the doc itself)

#### Why to use sequelize-typescript ?

As already mentionned! Sequelize have native support for typescript starting from `V5`. As per [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html). So why use a wrapper above it! That use decorators too! (I'm not against decorators! Some are! As per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60369189/7668448))

Ask yourself why ? Is there anything to sequelize-typescript! An important plus comparing to the native way ? If there is clear things! Please mention them in the comments! And i'll update! This section!

And if not! Native can be way better! A dependency or many in less!

#### Project configuration

tsconfig!

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "es2016",
            "dom"
        ],
        "declaration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules/**/*",
        "src/**/*.test.tsx",
        "src/**/*.story.tsx",
        "test/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Those are the two important things to add.

```json
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```

But that should not be your problem! Otherwise the project will throw compile errors!

## HELL

### Node js VERSION (V14 HELL)

And yea! That can be the cause! You may already used to have it work all right before! And then in a new computer or environment! **It's not working any more**!

**Node version can be the problem**! **Node v15** and **Node v14**! That's a known problem! I myself encountered once with `knex.js` and `postgres` (knex.js is a query builder)! So you can see that is related! In my story the code was working all right on my laptop and old vps that we deployed in! But then i deployed on a windows rdp! And mmm! Boom! Then i pulled my hair for some time! I reflected and checked! There was no change! And then i came to hey! I only updated nodejs! And later i found that other people encountered the same thing! In short! It all started on `nodejs v14` (i call this **v14 HELL**)! You can check my answer about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61622137/7668448)

And apparently the same problem is always there with `nodejs v15`!

In the question of this thread! We confirmed that! In my desktop all worked well! `Nodejs v12`! And with my friend computer! It didn't! `nodejs v14` and `nodejs v15`. Then i wanted to confirm! I installed `nodejs v15` And caboom! BINGO! The execution just stop unexpectedly! No logging ! No error! In `v12`! All was working correctly! i had errors at first then i corrected them! And the server was up and running! And sequelize connected to the DB!

#### Here the executions

#### V12 and v13

I'm displaying v13! The same happen with v12!

[image]

```sh
nvm use v13
Now using node v13.14.0 (npm v6.14.4)
 coderhero@HeroStation  ~/Documents/coderhero/Dev/projects/Fahima-ecommerce   LuckyLook  npm run dev 

> bagsshoes-server@1.0.0 dev /home/coderhero/Documents/coderhero/Dev/projects/Fahima-ecommerce
> npx ts-node-dev src/server.ts

[INFO] 01:49:29 ts-node-dev ver. 1.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 9.0.0, typescript ver. 4.0.5)
config ::::
{
  username: 'fahima',
  password: '123456',
  database: 'fahimashop',
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres'
}
hi there ::::
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
connection established
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Products" ("id"   SERIAL , "brand" TEXT, "price" DECIMAL, "description" VARCHAR(255), "imgUrl" VARCHAR(255), "category" VARCHAR(255), "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'Products' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
server running http://localhost:8100
press CTRL+C to stop server, please :)
```

Cool working no problem

#### V14 and v15 execution

#### v14

[image]

```sh
 coderhero@HeroStation  ~/Documents/coderhero/Dev/projects/Fahima-ecommerce   LuckyLook  node -v        
v14.15.0
 coderhero@HeroStation  ~/Documents/coderhero/Dev/projects/Fahima-ecommerce   LuckyLook  npm run dev

> bagsshoes-server@1.0.0 dev /home/coderhero/Documents/coderhero/Dev/projects/Fahima-ecommerce
> npx ts-node-dev src/server.ts

[INFO] 02:07:35 ts-node-dev ver. 1.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 9.0.0, typescript ver. 4.0.5)
config ::::
{
  username: 'fahima',
  password: '123456',
  database: 'fahimashop',
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres'
}
hi there ::::
 coderhero@HeroStation  ~/Documents/coderhero/Dev/projects/Fahima-ecommerce   LuckyLook 
```

And opps! The program is exiting unexpectedly with no error output!

#### V15

[image]

```sh
 coderhero@HeroStation  ~/Documents/coderhero/Dev/projects/Fahima-ecommerce   LuckyLook  nvm use v15    
Now using node v15.0.1 (npm v7.0.3)
 coderhero@HeroStation  ~/Documents/coderhero/Dev/projects/Fahima-ecommerce   LuckyLook  npm run dev

> bagsshoes-server@1.0.0 dev
> npx ts-node-dev src/server.ts

[INFO] 02:10:48 ts-node-dev ver. 1.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 9.0.0, typescript ver. 4.0.5)
config ::::
{
  username: 'fahima',
  password: '123456',
  database: 'fahimashop',
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres'
}
hi there ::::
 coderhero@HeroStation  ~/Documents/coderhero/Dev/projects/Fahima-ecommerce   LuckyLook 
```

And oppsii again! The program is exiting unexpectedly with no error output!

There is no difference too between `v14` and `v15`! It's `V14 HELL`.

#### In short

The **V14 HELL** is a known and very probable cause! There is a problem with `pg` module i guess! Something changed on `v14` and caused this problem!

In short short! If nothing is making any sense! And if your same code was working before! First thing to do! Is to check with nodejs `v13` or `v12`! That can save you from insanity! Who would say the version of nodejs and a new one will create such a problem!

#### What is this problem! What is V14 HELL in nodejs ?

If like me you like to know the details and what did happen !?

With node V14! Some breaking changes happened on the api! Also many things were changed! Including Openssl version!

For postgres! And `pg` module! The problem was as described in this [comment](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2170#issuecomment-617556848) per this [thread](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2170):

> The initial readyState (a private/undocumented API that
>
> pg uses) of net.Socket seems to have changed from 'closed' to 'open'
> in Node 14.
>
> It’s hard to fix with perfect backwards compatibility, but I think I
> have a patch that’s close enough.

And as per this [PR](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/2171)!

You can see the changes in [this diffing](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/2171/commits/149f48232445da0fb3022044e4f1c53509040ad3)

**In short** as mentioned! The behavior for `onReadySate` changed for `net.Socket` !
And the implemented solution was to not use `onReadyState` at all!

And as per this

> Connection now always calls connect on its stream when connect is called on it.

Check [this line](https://github.com/charmander/node-postgres/blob/149f48232445da0fb3022044e4f1c53509040ad3/packages/pg/lib/connection.js#L54)

In the older version the connect was called only if the socket is on `closed` state! `readyState` usage is eliminated!

You can understand! Depending on the implementation! Many things may or not be affected by those core changes!

#### Relevant node changes

And because i wanted to see where the change happen! Here you go and can check

https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/32272

One can check the log of changes too:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V14.md

#### FIX (Postgres v14 HELL)

As per my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61622137/7668448).

Upgrade `pg` driver to `>=8.0.3`! You can simply upgrade to latest!

```
npm install pg@latest --save
```

And you can check for our problem in question

Old version at `v7`

[image]

Updating to `v8`

[image]

Running again with `node v15`

[image]

Taraaaaa! And it worked awesomely!

And if you are not using `postgres`! And the problem was `v14 HELL`! Meaning You tested with `v13`. And it worked! Then try to upgrade your db driver to latest!

#### Why node v14 + exit and no logging error

Also to mention the breaking changes! Made `pg` make the process exit at `connect() call`. And that's what made it exit! And logging was to be seen!
In more detail for this! Here how it happened! Sequelize have the postgres dialect implementation! Which use pg! And pg client! create a connection! The connection have a `connect` event! When it connect it emit it! And because node v14 change the behavior to starting with open! The stream connection is skipped! And the stream is taken as connected! Where it is not! And the `connect` event is emitted directly! When that happen! The client either will call `requestSsl()` or `startup()` method of the connection object! And both will call `this._stream.write`. because the stream is not connected! An error happen! This error is not catch! Then the promise in sequelize driver! Will stay unresolved! And then the event loop get empty! Nodejs by default behavior just exit!

You can see the step through lines of code:

- [Sequelize pg adapter will call pg client to create a connection and the promise](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/febc083adee2cd3e6f24b18a556acdc4c4f50f96/src/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js#L123)
- [pg client call connect on a connection object](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/aafd8ac64e588e689ed08e7957bc3c91f8fe01e3/packages/pg/lib/client.js#L108)
- [pg connection `connect()` call and emit `connect`! Thinking the stream is connected because of V14 change](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/aafd8ac64e588e689ed08e7957bc3c91f8fe01e3/packages/pg/lib/connection.js#L56)
- [pg client `connect` event catched and callback run! `requestSsl()` or `startup()` will be run](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/aafd8ac64e588e689ed08e7957bc3c91f8fe01e3/packages/pg/lib/client.js#L115)
- One of the method get run and `stream.write` will be called ([requestSsl()](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/aafd8ac64e588e689ed08e7957bc3c91f8fe01e3/packages/pg/lib/connection.js#L140), [startup()](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/aafd8ac64e588e689ed08e7957bc3c91f8fe01e3/packages/pg/lib/connection.js#L164))
- Stream Error (not catched)
- [Promise](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/febc083adee2cd3e6f24b18a556acdc4c4f50f96/src/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js#L123) in sequelize postgres adapter! Still unresolved!
- event loop empty => Nodejs => Exit

#### Why nodejs exit (unresolved promises)

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22088

[Node exits without error and doesn't await promise (Event callback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914025/node-exits-without-error-and-doesnt-await-promise-event-callback)

[what happens when a Promise never resolves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966890/what-happens-when-a-promise-never-resolves)

#### NVM

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

If you don't know what `nvm` is! Or you are not using `nvm`. Consider using it! As it's a very interesting tool! **Nvm is a node version management tool**!

With nvm changing, debugging and testing to and with different version of nodejs! Is quick and a breeze! And so installing new versions of nodejs in parallel!

### Note about sequelize.sync()

Do not use it for `production`! Or at all! (Most of ORM! And query builder (knex.js) use migrations).

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#synchronization-in-production

From the doc

> As shown above, sync({ force: true }) and sync({ alter: true }) can be
> destructive operations. Therefore, they are not recommended for
> production-level software. Instead, synchronization should be done
> with the advanced concept of [Migrations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html), with the help of the
> [Sequelize CLI](https://github.com/sequelize/cli).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and rich answer. However, I've found out that the problem was related to windows, I siwtched back to Ubuntu and everything worked like a charm. Me on the contrary, I have issues using node 12, but using node V14.7.0 works just like a charm for me. So, I used the same json package, and everything worked. Still don't know why this issue happens particularly on Windows.

Comment: Can you check what version of pg is installed on node_modules. Because a problem should happen. I'm running debian. And tested as per the answer. So it's absolutely not a question of windows vs linux. Is everything working with no problem ? You are using pg. Can you confirm pg version both on package.json and node_modules !

Comment: Hi, I'm using "pg": "^7.9.0"

Comment: You checked that on node_modules ?

Comment: In last August, I worked with the exact package.json and with node V14.7.0, I used pg: 7.9.0, and everything worked perfectly, Node 12 has always caused me a lot of headache. Now, I've just checked again, and indeed, needed to upgrade the version of "pg" to "8.3.0" . Thanks for the impressive answer.I'll set it as an accepted answer.

Comment: So basically either you didn't use v14. Or v14 didn't made the change at the time. Or you didn't use postgres. May be mysql !!

Comment: I used Node V14.7.0, I'm certain. Node 12 cause dme some headache, so back then switched to Node 14.7.0 and got it done for me.

Comment: This was a thoroughly entertaining read.

Comment: Glade to hear that hhh